# Enterprise Library 5.0 Caching block and Oracle as Database cache storage

Tags: caching, enterprise-library

We are trying to see that if at all it is possible to use Oracle as Database cache storage. Has anyone came accross this scenario?

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the Caching Application Block to use the Data Access block, which in turn may be configured to use an Oracle database.